# Facebook App: How to get interest-lists posts/feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm new to programming Facebook apps, so please forgive my ignorance and my use of non-formal terms.

There is an option on Facebook to create mixed lists of friends, liked-pages, and subscriptions so that you can see a "custom feed" containing posts only from the members of the list.

If a user is subscribed to such a list, can my app access the "custom feed"? Or at least the array of members of this list? (which I can then iterate through and fetch the posts published by these members)

I've read about the FriendList object of the Graph API, but when I tested it on myself with [This Link](https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAHZClApws0N4W9c3pFCtZChLMTz1ECwcbOORkCJCtF6I1bAoYllcTFRejBcZBQvTvVRZBfcX6qUBmhQR0y4DfmHXRZA9chQZDZD) (sources: [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), [FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)), it didn't show all of my created lists, but only those that are strictly defined as "friend lists" - i.e. lists containing only friends (and not liked-pages or subscriptions).
But I've noticed three things-

1. On my homepage the "friend-lists" (those that do appear in the above link) have a different icon (a little blue person) than the "mixed-lists" (a blue square with an "rss-wave" icon)
2. All of my "friend-lists" are old lists which I have created a few years ago. The newer lists are "mixed-lists". I can tell the difference both by the icon and the fact that the new lists don't appear in the above link.
3. When I added a liked-page to one of my "friend-lists" it did not change its type (same icon and still appears in the above link).

Which leads me to these questions-

- What is the difference between these types of lists?
- And for that matter how many types of lists are there? Are they managed differently?
- How can my app access these "mixed-lists"? I want a list of all the lists the user is subscribed to, and I want my app to be able to read the posts published on these lists.

I hope that was clear enough.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I noticed another big difference between these types of lists: the "friend-lists" show up under the "Friends" headline on the left side menu (when you press "more" you can see all of them). The "mixed-lists" as I called them show up under the "Interests" headline. So this must be the difference. I think they are pretty much the same as far as what types of members you can add to the list. The difference must be that "friend-lists" are only for the user who created them, while "interest-lists" (a.k.a "mixed-lists") can be published and subscribed to by other people.

I'll try to find documentation about "interest-lists". If anyone already knows the answer please share :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it – created a list, added one of my friends and one of the pages I’m a fan of to it.

It shows up in the Graph API explorer with `"list_type": "user_created"` – but /listid/members only shows the friend I put onto that list, not the page.

This is consistent with [what the docs say](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) on the members connection,

> members: All of the *users* who are members of this list.

So there currently seems to be no way to get info about pages on such lists. (Anybody knows something different, they might correct me.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found something else and edited my question. Do you know something about that?

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Just wanted to let you know that I'm not checking it as the "accepted answer" on the off chance that there will be a way to do it in the future and I'll get another response.